# How can I change encoding of "Show Create Table" result in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, encoding

There is a view table created with a mis-encoded query.
Interestingly, the results of "show create table" and "mysqldump" were different.
The result of "show create table" showed the incorrectly encoded part with a question marks.
However, the result of "mysqldump" shows the incorrectly encoded part as the value of bytes.
I want to show like mysqldump result.

```
mysql> show create table test_view;
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`tester`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW
`test_view` AS select `test_table`.`idx` AS `Index`,
`test_table`.`tel` AS `???IP` from `test_table` order by `test_table`.`idx`
```

Use mysqldump...

```
/*!50001 VIEW `test_view` AS 
select `test_table`.`idx` AS `Index`,`test_table`.`tel` AS `�ъ⑹踰IP` 
from `test_table` 
order by `test_table`.`idx` */;
```

Comment: What character set setting did you use on `mysqldump`?

Comment: @RickJames I did not use the character set option when using mysqldump. MySQL default character set is Latin1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL [character_set_results](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_results) configuration variable decides the encoding of the results sent back to the client. Use the same character set from the CLI interface as you use from mysqldump to get the same results. `set names` also sets this variable.

Comment: I looked in mysqldump source code with the 'set names' you gave me. And I confirmed that changed the result character set using "set names binary" in the view table dump code. This command returns the result I wanted.